# handling missing input variable for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, missing-data, predictor

In building feature-sets for a machine learning algorithm, I'm facing a situation where the input variable - which is a numeric variable, may or may not appear. What I mean is, the data set I'm getting is very chaotic, and in many situations the input value may not be available. How to represent such a value? To give an example:

```
Age Days Likes
45  5    3 
33  6    0
```

Now, suppose I've a situation where Age is not available, but Days and other variables are available like this-

```
Age   Days Likes
NotA   4    1
```

Here NotA is just saying Not Available. Now, if the machine learning algorithm handles only "numbers" (not categories/factors as in R), and if I cannot neglect such rows or instances as there are too many of rows where Age is not available, how do represent it in numbers?

Could this be an option?

```
AgeYes AgeNo Age Days Like
1      0     45  5    3
1      0     33  6    0
0      1      0  4    1
```

What other options I have? What would be best way to handle such data?